# Import MDG Technologies to Model

Tags: enterprise-architect

Through C# plugin can we load the MDG to the model.if  yes what is API providied by EA to load the MDG file to the Model.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for the function `EA.Repository.ImportTechnology(string Technology)`

> ImportTechnology (string Technology)
>
> Boolean
>
> Notes: Installs a given MDG Technology resource into the repository.
>
> Returns True if the technology is successfully loaded into the model.
>   Otherwise returns False.
>
> This applies to technologies imported into pre-7.0 versions of
>   Enterprise Architect (imported technologies), not to technologies
>   referenced in version 7.0 and later (referenced technologies).
>
> Parameters:
>
> Technology: String - the contents of the technology resource file

See the [manual](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/repository3.html) for more info

Comment: So we cannot import the technology for EA 12.1

Comment: Can't we import the technology that are created in EA 12.1 or this API is not supported for EA 12.1

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation for 12.1?

Comment: Yes. In the document it is mentioned that "This applies to technologies imported into pre-7.0 versions of Enterprise Architect (imported technologies), not to technologies referenced in version 7.0 and later (referenced technologies)."

Comment: The proof of the pudding is in the eating. The best way to find out is to try it and see what happens.

Comment: yes the Import technology can import the MDG to the Model but its stereotypes are not getting loaded after MDG is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 public object EA_OnInitializeTechnologies(EA.Repository Repository)
 {
    return MyProject.Properties.Resources.yourMDGxml;
 }
```

It will load an MDG and enable it.

Add the created mdg xml in the resource of the c# project and return it in the above broadcast event .

**EA_OnInitializeTechnologies** broadcast event used to pass an technology for loading.

Please refer sparx help for more details

[EA_OnInitializeTechnologies](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/ea_oninitialize_technologies.html)

[Deploy an MDG](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/modeling_tools/deploying_mdg_technologies.html)